# Javascript Table & Number Format

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a simple table. I am looking to modify the number format of my 2nd last td element (where I fetch "SumPrices" to a currency rounded to the dollar. I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" style="width: 25%;">
  <tbody> 
     <tr> 
        <th scope="col"> Fiscal </th> 
        <th scope="col"> Courses </th> 
        <th scope="col"> Cost </th> 
        <th scope="col"> Comment </th> 
     </tr> 
     <tr> 
        <td align="center"> 2019-20</td>
        <td align="center" id="Icount">252</td>
        <td align="center" id="SumPrices">323662</td>
        <td align="center"> Something </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will presumably be populating the contents of the table from a source? At the point of insertion / DOM manipulation is when you would format the number from your data source to be a currency. You would likely do this in javascript as per your question tag.

i.e.

```
formattedNumber = format(dataSource)
td.innerText = formattedNumber
```

Example:

```js
let cost = document.querySelector("#SumPrices").innerHTML.trim();
/*casting to number*/
cost = +cost;

cost = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "USD",
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
}).format(cost);

document.querySelector("#SumPrices").innerHTML = cost;
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" style="width: 25%;">
  <tbody> 
     <tr> 
        <th scope="col"> Fiscal </th> 
        <th scope="col"> Courses </th> 
        <th scope="col"> Cost </th> 
        <th scope="col"> Comment </th> 
     </tr> 
     <tr> 
        <td align="center"> 2019-20</td>
        <td align="center" id="Icount">252</td>
        <td align="center" id="SumPrices">323662</td>
        <td align="center"> Something </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

Lots of ways to format your number, you could use the regex as suggested by Sajeeb. You could also use a Intl.NumberFormatted. MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Great guide on using this for currency here: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-format-number-as-currency-javascript/

Is this helpful?

Comment: You're welcome. Concrete example from ambianBeing :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toFixed(precision)` and `regex` for formating currency.

```js
const td = document.querySelector("#SumPrices");
let price = parseInt(td.innerText);

price = price.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');

td.innerText = '$ ' + price;
```

```css
table {
 width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" style="width: 25%;">
  <tbody> 
     <tr> 
        <th scope="col"> Fiscal </th> 
        <th scope="col"> Courses </th> 
        <th scope="col"> Cost </th> 
        <th scope="col"> Comment </th> 
     </tr> 
     <tr> 
        <td align="center"> 2019-20</td>
        <td align="center" id="Icount">252</td>
        <td align="center" id="SumPrices">323662</td>
        <td align="center"> Something </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```